# What happens when `exit(1)` is run in a PHP script via Apache?

Tags: php, apache

I'm wondering if anything significant happens when exiting with a non-zero value? Does Apache just ignore the return value since it's not run in a command line environment?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Apache will ignore it. It is only useful in a command line environment.

Comment: Do you know of any Apache documentation which confirms this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I've tried getting Apache to log it (because it usually does that for its child processes) and couldn't do that no matter what. That could be dependent on the PHP SAPI in use though.